# Let R denote the ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle1+3i\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let R denote the ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle1+3i\rangle$.

Show that $i − 3 ∈  \langle 1 + 3i\rangle $
and that $[i] = [3]$ in $R$. Use this to prove
that $[10] = [0]$ in $R$ and that $[a + bi] = [a + 3b]$, where $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

So, $\langle 1+3i\rangle=a*(1+3i)$ for some $a\in R$ right? I don't see how there is any value of $a$ that satisfies $i-3=a*(1+3i)$. Then how do I use that to prove the equivalence classes are equal?

Comment: Rather, $\langle 1+3i\rangle$ is the set of all $a(1+3i)$ where $a\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we show that $i-3 \in \langle 1+3i \rangle$.

We need to find $r,s \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $i-3=(r+si)(1+3i)$

$\rightarrow i-3 = (r-3s)+(s+3r)i$

Matching coefficients, we see that $s=1,r=0$ is a solution.

Since $i-3 \in \langle 1+3i \rangle$, we have that:

$[i-3] = [0]$ in $R$

$\rightarrow [i]-[3]=[0]$

$\rightarrow [i]=[3]$

To see that $[10]=[0]$ in $R$, we use the facts that $[i]=[3]$ and $[0]=[i-3]$:

$[0]=[0]^2=[i-3]^2=([i]+[-3])^2= [-1]-[6][i]+[9]=[-1]-[6][3]+[9]=[-10]$

$\rightarrow [0] = [10]$ (multipy both sides by $[-1]$)

To see that $[a+bi]=[a+3b]$ we again use the fact that $[i]=[3]$:

$[a+bi]=[a]+[b][i]=[a]+[b][3]=[a+b3]$

Answer (score 1):

Since $i-3=i(1+3i)$, $i-3\in\langle1+3i\rangle$. So, in $R$ you have $[i-3]=0$; in other words, $[i]=[3]$. Therefore, if $b\in\Bbb Z$, $[bi]=[3b]$, and therefore, if $a\in\Bbb Z$, $[a+bi]=[a+3b]$.